# Issue in Hiding/Showing a panel on RadioButtonList using JQuery

Tags: jquery, .net

1)I have a dropdown list on my page wit options "Credit Card" abd "Invoice/Direct Bill".On the selection  of "Invoice/Direct Bill" , I don't have to anything but on selection of "Credit Card":
2) I have to show/hide radiobuttonlist(inside a Panel:Panel2) , which has got 3 options (Check-In Date, Book Date, Other Date)
3)If I  click on "Other Date" Option of radiobuttonlist , I have to show a Textbox , which is inside a Panel :Panel3 .
4)If I click on "Check-In Date" or "Book Date" option of radiobuttonlist , I have to hide the text box , which is inside Panel3.

All my 4 scenarios are working.
The problem :
If I select "Credit Card" in dropdownlist , select " Other Date" option in my radiobuttonlist , enter a value "10" in my textbox and click on submit button , post back occurs and my value gets stored in DB.
When I reload the page :
I get"Credit Card" in dropdownlist , "Credit Card" option in my radiobutton list , but text box with value 15 is not visible.When I select "Check-In Date"/"Book Date" and then "Other Date" , I see my text box with value 15.The code is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('select[id$=ddlCardType]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == -1) {
            $('div[id$=Panel1]').show();
            $('div[id$=Panel2]').hide();
            $('div[id$=Panel3]').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('div[id$=Panel1]').hide();
            $('div[id$=Panel2]').show();
        }
    }).change();

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panel = $("#Panel3");
    var cbo = $("#Panel2").find("cboVisibility");
    $("#cboVisibility").find('input:radio').change(function (index) {
        //$("#Panel2 cboVisibility").find('input:radio').change(function (index) {
        //$("[id*=pnl2 cboVisibility input:radio]").change(function (index) {
        if ($(this).val() == "OD")
            panel.show();
        else
            panel.hide()
    });
    $('#cboVisibility').find('input:radio').trigger('change');
});
</script>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCardType" runat="server" CssClass="arial11nr" Width="270px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Invoice/Direct Bill</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="SUCC">Credit Card</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<td align="left" valign="top">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
        <strong>Billing Instructions/Notes</strong><span class="red-color">(optional)  
</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBillingInstructions" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine">
 </asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none;" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="cboVisibility" CssClass="Normal" runat="server" 
 RepeatDirection="Vertical"
            ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:ListItem Value="CD" Selected="True">Check-In Date</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BD">Book Date</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="OD">Other Date</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="display: none;" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <strong>Charge</strong>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSUCCValidity" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
        <strong>Days Before Check-In</strong>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="txtSUCCValidity"
            ErrorMessage="<br />Not valid Range" MaximumValue="999"  
ValidationGroup="update"
            MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
    </asp:Panel>
</td>
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing makes sense. By default the panel2 is hidden. Your js code will display the panel only if the radio buttons trigger a change event and that too a change that selects the third option. When you load the page after submitting the form, the radio button is set to the third option before the document is ready. ie, before the change event can be subscribe to. Which is why you dont see the textbox by default.

What needs to be changed to enable your scenario, that depends on how you are setting the value for the radio button.

One solution is to trigger a change event on document ready. Like so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panel = $("#Panel2");
    var cbo = $("#Panel1").find("cboVisibility");
    $("#cboVisibility").find('input:radio').change(function (index) {

        // when triggering a change across all radio inputs, even 
        // those that are not selected will show up here. 
        // hence the check to verify if they are actually selected. 
        if (this.value == "OD" && this.checked) {  
            panel.show();

        // we wand to hide the panel3 only if an option other
        // than "OD" is selected.
        } else if (this.checked) {
            panel.hide(); 
        }
    });

    // this will trick the browser into thinking that you selected the third option
    $('#cboVisibility').find('input:radio').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Amith George:If I am doing this , then The Contents of Panel2 is shown on :
The select of "Yes"/"No" options of radiobutton and also when I select "B" in my dropdownlist which is not my requirement.
Requirement :
Panel2 should be visible only when we have "A" selected on dropdownlist and "None" selected in RadioButtonList

Comment: Based on the code you have posted, if the user clicks Yes/No, the value of $(this).val() will be "CD" or "BD" and not "OD". The panel is being shown only if the value is "OD". If its not behaving like this on your end, I recommend you post the code that you actually are using. The only change I have done is triggering the change event once on page load. And if you think about it, that shouldnt affect any other behaviour.

Comment: Preferably, create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with only the html/css/js. That way both of us will be on the same page, no pun intended.

Comment: Amith George :I have just posted the origional complate code.
Please have a look at it.

Comment: Amityh George , I have edited the description according to the code.Please have a look at it.

Comment: Have updated my answer. Added a check to see if the value is actually selected or not, in the radio button change handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var panel = $("#Panel3");
var cbo = $("#Panel2").find("cboVisibility");

$(document).ready(function () {
    //var ddlCardType = "<%=ddlCardType.ClientID %>";
    if ($('[id*=ddlCardType]>option:selected').val() == "SUCC" &&    
$('[id*=cboVisibility] :checked').val() == "OD") {
        panel.show();
    }
});


$('select[id$=ddlCardType]').change(function () {
    if (this.value == -1) {
        $('div[id$=Panel1]').show();
        $('div[id$=Panel2]').hide();
        $('div[id$=Panel3]').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('div[id$=Panel1]').hide();
        $('div[id$=Panel2]').show();
        if ($('[id*=cboVisibility] :checked').val() == "OD")
            panel.show();
    }
}).change();



$("#cboVisibility").find('input:radio').change(function (index) {
    //$("#Panel2 cboVisibility").find('input:radio').change(function (index) {
    //$("[id*=pnl2 cboVisibility input:radio]").change(function (index) {
    if ($(this).val() == "OD")
        panel.show();
    else
        panel.hide()
});
```